# uibutton in uitableviewcell is giving me indexpath one less than actual indexpath iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to find the row for a `UITableViewCell` when the user presses a `UIButton` which is a `subview` of the cell. Using the following code, I reliably get one less than the actual `indexpath`. Anybody know why this is/if this is a good way to find the `indexpath` of a cell using a `subview` (in this case a `UIButton`) in iOS7?

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_messageTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_messageTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
if (indexPath != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"highlightedcell: %i",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: Change `CGPointZero` to `CGPointMake(5,5)` and you should get better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the button tag and get the index path of clicked button.

```
[yourButton setTag:indexPath.row];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)yourButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:yourTableView];
    NSIndexPath *deliverIndPath = [yourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSLog(@"deliverIndPath : %@",deliverIndPath);
}
```

Comment: what does setting the tag have to do with getting the indexpath?

Comment: if you are creating multiple buttons in tableview then set indexpath.row as button tag and while click to button (id)sender through that you will get indexpath of that clicked button row. In DeliveryIndPath is indexpath.

Answer (score 0):

As per my Suggestion do the following:

Set the button tag to indexPath.row as below:

```
 cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Now add a selector on that button like the following sample code:

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now implement the selector and find the index of the selected row as below:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {    
       UIButton *btnTemp=(UIButton *)sender;
       NSLog(@"%d",btnTemp.tag);
}
```

So in the btnTemp.tag you can find the ccorrect index of the selected cell